# How do I create a styleClass to use this CSS?

Tags: css

How do create a styleClass for the following CSS? I want it only to be used in one particular section of the form - the tabbed menu - and not affect anything else. If I leave it as is, everything on the form is affected by it.

```
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#5576A7;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#ff9c2a;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `class` to your link, and reference that in your CSS.

With the markup:

```
<a href="..." class="myClass">My Link</a>
```

And with the CSS:

```
a.myClass:link,a.myClass:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#5576A7;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a.myClass:hover,a.myClass:active
{
background-color:#ff9c2a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it looks so obvious once you see it in print

Answer (score 1):

You can set a class in html like this:

```
<a href="/url" class="someclass">hello world</a>
```

And then you can limit the styles to this class in css like this:

```
a.someclass:link, a.someclass:visited {
    ...
}

a.someclass:hover, a.someclass:active {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a class or ID to do so.

For you tab you can use an ID like this:

```
<div id="specialTab">
    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
</div>
```

and change your CSS like this:

```
#specialTab a:link, #specialTab a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#5576A7;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#specialTab a:hover, #specialTab a:active
{
background-color:#ff9c2a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1) Give each element a class ("tab" in this case):

```
a.tab:link, a.tab:visited { ... }
```

2) Use a container group. Say your tab menu has id "tabMenu":

```
#tabMenu a:link, #tabMenu a:visited { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the menu in a div with the id 'menu'

Then just

```
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited 
{ 
display:block; 
width:120px; 
font-weight:bold; 
color:#ffffff; 
background-color:#5576A7; 
text-align:center; 
padding:4px; 
text-decoration:none; 
text-transform:uppercase; 
} 
#menu a:hover,#menu a:active 
{ 
background-color:#ff9c2a; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), either assign a class or use the class of closest parent to style your `<a>` tags. e.g.

```
.tabbed-menu a:link, .tabbed-menu a:visited {
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#5576A7;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.tabbed-menu a:hover, .tabbed-menu a:active {
    background-color:#ff9c2a;
}
```

Where `.tabbed-menu` would be the class used by your menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to style just a section in a form part you can give this section an Id like here:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
     <ul>
       <li id="style-me"> </li>
       <li> </li>
      </ul>
   <fieldset>
</form>


#style-me a:link, #style-me a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#5576A7;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#ff9c2a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply styles on specific parts of your html you must use selectors:

First add div or other tag with unique id set around elements you need to change.

```
<div id="zone_name">
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

In style add id selector and tag name

```
#zone_name a {
/*style attributes for a tag in zone_name*/
}

#zone_name span {
/*style attributes for span tag in zone_name*/
}
```